# Drupal 7 translate blog page 'title' and 'URL alias' with i18n

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internationalization

I'm currently setting my Drupal 7 site up in an additional language using the i18n and variable translation.

My problem is that I cannot **update the title of the blog page or the URL alias** when I switch to the version for the other language. When I switch language my posts are translated but I cannot find where to change the titles of the page or the URL alias.

I'd like the routes to look something like this:

```
mydomain.com/news
mydomain.com/es/noticias
```

Comment: Have you read https://www.drupal.org/node/1268692?

Comment: I have not, will read now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hi, I've just given this a read and this article assumes that I'm creating a view for the blog in the first place(see the part of the article headed 'Views and internationalization'). However my news page doesn't seem to be powered by any 'view'. I've been through all my views and tried to find which one edits the 'news' page and cannot find it. I'm assuming that the 'news' page is powered much like how Wordpress does it by setting a page as the 'blog' page in settings. But I can't find the same kind of thing in Drupal. Any thoughts pleaseeee? Thank you. :)

Comment: Standard literature for setting up a news page is https://www.drupal.org/node/1924660, see also https://www.drupal.org/node/266550

Answer (score 0):

There are different kind of translations supported in Drupal. By default translation is made buy matching nodes in different languages togheter. And adding new translation actually means making new node and matching it with rest marked together.

But also you can translate fields. So in this case you don't have different nodes, but field values are translated. And if I remember well you can't translate all fields, i.e. you can't translate title and path since it's one node. Is this a case?

Update:

You would need to add "title" module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/title

Check out please this article:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1280910

Comment: Hi MilanG, my news page being one node sounds about right because as I mentioned I don't have a 'news' page I can actually edit.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can edit the title and URL alias?
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Installing that module doesn't seem to have helped. However I have just found that my page title seems to come from the the taxonomy term (http://mysite.co.uk/taxonomy/term/42/edit). I've just looked it up here () but can't seem to find out how to enable translation of taxonomies. Would you happen to know how to translate taxonomy names?

Comment: Check out template file for your page. Maybe there is some (php) code that is setting page title, following some algorithm.